# Parse and convert denorm numbers?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

In C++, we can store denorm numbers into variables without problems:

```
double x = std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min();
```

Then, we can print this variable without problems:

```
std::cout<<std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10)
std::cout<<std::scientific;
std::cout<<x;
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

And it will print:

```
4.94065645841246544e-324
```

But a problem occurs when one tries to parse this number. Imagine that this number is stored inside a file, and read as a string. The problem is that:

```
std::string str = "4.94065645841246544e-324";
double x = std::stod(str);
```

will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception.

So my question is: **how to convert a denorm value stored in a string?**

Comment: I hypothesize the `stod` implementation in your C++ implementation is deficient. The C++ standard might not be strict about how various floating-point operations must be implemented, but any implementation of reasonable quality ought to be able to parse this. You should report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood the problem, but using `std::istringstream` like this:

```
std::string str = "4.94065645841246544e-324";
double x;
std::istringstream iss(str);
iss >> x;
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
std::cout << std::scientific;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

...gives me:

```
4.94065645841246544e-324
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can use the `strtod` (or the older `atof`) interface from `cstdlib`. I doubt whether this is guaranteed or portable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but you are actually printing:

`(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 + 1) = 18` decimal digits.

e.g., an IEEE-754 64-bit double with round-trip precision is `"1.16"` in *scientific* notation. Perhaps this is introducing some ULP / rounding that interferes with the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with denormals and `std::stod` is that the latter is defined in terms of `std::strtod`, which may set `errno=ERANGE` on underflow (it's implementation-defined whether it'll do, and in glibc it does). As reminded [by gcc developers](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86409#c2), in such a case `std::stod` is defined by the standard to throw `std::out_of_range`.

So your proper workaround is to use `std::strtod` directly, ignoring `ERANGE` when the value it returns is finite and nonzero, like here:

```
double stringToDouble(const char* str, std::size_t* pos=nullptr)
{
    errno=0;
    char* end;
    const auto x=std::strtod(str, &end);
    if(errno==ERANGE)
    {
        // Ignore it for denormals
        if(x!=0 && x>-HUGE_VAL && x<HUGE_VAL)
            return x;
        throw std::out_of_range("strtod: ERANGE");
    }
    else if(errno)
        throw std::invalid_argument("strtod failed");
    if(pos)
        *pos=end-str;
    return x;
}
```

Note that, unlike `std::istringstream` approach suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626486/673852), this will work for hexfloats too.